# Send request parameters to another controller/action in zend 1

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, controller

i am working in zend project and need to post request to certain page via ajax. Then i need to carry the request data and post it to another controller and action of same project which should return me some data as well.

Comment: Can you post your code attempts or the controller&action through which you would like to navigate?

Comment: i need alternate of curl/file_get_contents to access another controller's action and need to get response.